# How to order result by different indicators in clickhouse with grouparray()

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

I have a table "product_info" like this

```
ProductId   ProductName
f0001       L1
f0002       L2
f0002       L2
f0002       L2
d0001       P3-01
d0001       P3-01
...
```

I want to know how many unique "productName" values in the table, and then list them in an array:

```
SELECT select grouparray(DISTINCT Product)  AS unique from product_info
```

Now, I tried to order my result. In MySQL I can do like this:

```
SELECT select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Product ORDER BY Product)  AS unique from product_info
```

But in clickhouse, it returns a error:

```
SELECT select grouparray(DISTINCT Product ORDER BY product)  AS unique from product_info

Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 31 ('order'): order by *input expression*. Expected one of: token, Dot, UUID, Comma, ClosingRoundBracket, OR, AND, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN, LIKE, ILIKE, NOT LIKE, NOT ILIKE, IN, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN, GLOBAL NOT IN, MOD, DIV, IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, alias, AS. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 22.12.3.5 (official build))
```

How to fix this error? My expected result looks like:

```
ORDER BY NAME:

unique
{L1,L2,P3-01}


ORDER BY COUNT:

UNIQUE
{L1,P3-01,L2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit subquery to find the distinct products, and then aggregate that:

```sql
SELECT GROUPARRAY(Product) AS unique
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM product_info) t;
```

Comment: I tried Tim's answer and works for me. `select groupArray(NameValue) from (SELECT DISTINCT ProductName as NameValue FROM product)`

Answer (score 1):

Try these ones:

```sql
SELECT arraySort(groupUniqArray(ProductName)) AS result
FROM
(
    /* Emulate the source dataset. */
    SELECT
        data.1 AS ProductId,
        data.2 AS ProductName
    FROM
    (
        SELECT arrayJoin([('f0001', 'L1'), ('f0002', 'L2'), ('f0002', 'L2'), ('f0002', 'L2'), ('d0001', 'P3-01'), ('d0001', 'P3-01')]) AS data
    )
);

/*
┌─result──────────────┐
│ ['L1','L2','P3-01'] │
└─────────────────────┘
*/
```

```sql
SELECT groupArray(ProductName) AS result
FROM (
  SELECT ProductName
  FROM
  (
      /* Emulate the source dataset. */
      SELECT
          data.1 AS ProductId,
          data.2 AS ProductName
      FROM
      (
          SELECT arrayJoin([('f0001', 'L1'), ('f0002', 'L2'), ('f0002', 'L2'), ('f0002', 'L2'), ('d0001', 'P3-01'), ('d0001', 'P3-01')]) AS data
      )
  )
  GROUP BY ProductName
  ORDER BY count()
);

/*
┌─result──────────────┐
│ ['L1','P3-01','L2'] │
└─────────────────────┘
*/
```